How to realign a semi-frameless shower door
I need to realign my shower door that has dropped from the top hinge about 80mm so unable to close properly. I've tried to Loosen the top hinge by unscrewing but the screw is encased in the hinge mechanism and will not Loosen off.

We are going to need more pictures, preferably of the entire shower door.

80mm? That's 3 3/16" you mean 8mm right?

And photos that show the screws you tried to loosen off.

Hi yes sorry 8mm, new photos added. Thanks

These are glass clamps/hangers. It looks like the way it works is that the screw drives a wedge that applies pressure to the glass to hold it in place. You may have already reached the end of its travel. The pads that cushion the glass are also moving.
If there is still travel in the screw (Try turning the screw in to see if the tab inside the housing moves. If it does, try backing it out until you no longer see it move.), you could try levering the glass up from the bottom to move the glass back into position and then tightening the screw.
That being said, this clamp/hanger looks like it is ready to fall out of the support bar.  The clamp looks like it is proprietary. Consider replacing the door if you plan to stay in your home for a while.
